# Google sheets query, group by and pivot between two dates

Tags: pivot, google-sheets-formula, between, google-query-language

I really need your help. After hours, I cant figure out, how can I combine these two together:

```
=QUERY(data!A:L;"select D,  COUNT(D) group by(D) pivot A";1)

=QUERY(data!A:L;"select D WHERE D >= date '"&TEXT(A1;"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' AND  D<= date '"&TEXT(B1;"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'  ";1)
```

I need the dataset as is visible on the "unfiltered" sheet:
[image]
but in between two dates.

This is the dataset:
[image]

This is the sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1n6dtmMdbbG4qG7HXYI2vdA3cBDNnbtt1i6a7Cw9gdhA/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
=QUERY(data!A:L;"select D, COUNT(D) WHERE D >= date '"&text(date(2020;12;1);"yyyy-MM-dd")&"' AND D <= date '"&text(date(2020;12;10);"yyyy-MM-dd")&"' group by(D) pivot A ";1)
```

I have inputed my own dates `date(2020;12;1)` and `date(2020;12;10)`, because I don't know where do you have them defined.